# converting array of strings to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, classcastexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assigning an array to an ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746639/assigning-an-array-to-an-arraylist-in-java)

How can I convert a array of strings like :

```
String logsSplitFromUrdu[] = fromTheRecentLogFile.split("غزل");
```

into a `ArrayList<String>` ?

**Edit:**

I was doing like when I get an error :

```
ArrayList<String> time = (ArrayList<String>)Arrays.asList(logsSplitFromUrdu);
```

**EDIT :**

Exception that I get when do the above :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:26)
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Did you go through the documentation of : - [Array#asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Comment: What error?  Or is guessing part of the fun?

Comment: @AndrewThompson error that it cannot be casted

Comment: Please copy/paste the new information into the question as an edit, and use code formatting on it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson added the exception

Comment: asList returns a List<String> not an ArrayList<String>.  99.9% of the time, that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658867/why-does-arrays-aslist-return-its-own-arraylist-implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) from the `Arrays` class. It will return a `List` of the correct generic type (`String` in this case):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(logsSplitFromUrdu);
```

If you absolutely need an `ArrayList<String>` and a `List<String>` won't do, then write one additional line after the previous one:

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`Arrays#asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29). This method returns a `fixed size` list.

So, if you are **`ok with fixed size list`**, then you can use this: -

```
List<String> fixedList = Arrays.asList(logsSplitFromUrdu);
```

But, if you **`want to modify`** your newly created `List`, you need to create it like this: -

```
ArrayList<String> modifiableList = 
             new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(logsSplitFromUrdu))
```

**BUT you should not do it like this**: -

```
ArrayList<String> modifiableList = 
                  (ArrayList<String>)Arrays.asList(logsSplitFromUrdu))
```

**It will give you `ClassCastException`**, because, the list returned from `Arrays.asList` is of type: - `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` and it cannot be cast to : - `java.util.ArrayList`

**UPDATE**: - [`java.util.Arrays#ArrayList`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/Arrays%24ArrayList.html) is a static class defined in `Arrays` class.

Comment: `java.util.List.ArrayList` I doubt if it even exists !

Comment: @Y.E.P Sorry its. java.util.Arrays.ArrayList. Will modify it..

Comment: @Y.E.P See this excellent Post: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658867/why-does-arrays-aslist-return-its-own-arraylist-implementation  for more information about this

Answer (score 0):

The return type of

```
Arrays.asList(logsSplitFromUrdu);
```

is `List<String>` and cannot be cast to `ArrayList<String>`. Instead you can use:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(logsSplitFromUrdu);
```

which returns an unmodifiable list. To get a modifiable list you could use:

```
ArrayList<String> modifyiableList = new ArrayList<String>(myList); 
modifyiableList.add("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

U have to use asList method of java.util.Arrays, refer the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Arrays.asList()` method to convert the `array` into `ArrayList`

```
String logsSplitFromUrdu[] = fromTheRecentLogFile.split("غزل");

ArrayList<String> arList = new ArrayList<String>(Array.asList(logsSplitFromUrdu));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a for loop to copy all of the elements from the array into a new ArrayList like so:

```
ArrayList<String> logsList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < logsSplitFromUrdu.length; i++)
{
    logsList.add(logsSplitFromUrdu[i]);
}
```

And after this logsList will contain all of the elements in your original array.