# How to convert a comma separated String to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

I have a comma separated String which i need to convert to ArrayList .
I tried this way

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String CommaSeparated = "item1 , item2 , item3";

            ArrayList<String> items = (ArrayList)Arrays.asList(CommaSeparated.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

            for(String str : items)
            {
                System.out.println(str);
            }

        }

    }
```

Its giving me the Runtime Error as shown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at com.tradeking.at.process.streamer.Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

as i was trying to convert an List to arrayList by force .

Comment: try `ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(CommaSeparated.split("\\s*,\\s*")))`

Comment: This question may be of use:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658867/why-does-arrays-aslist-return-its-own-arraylist-implementation

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `ArrayList` returned by `Arrays.asList` is not `java.util.ArrayList`. It's `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`. So you can't cast it to `java.util.ArrayList`.

You need to pass the list to the constructor of `java.util.ArrayList` class:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(CommaSeparated.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
```

or, you can simply assign the result:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(CommaSeparated.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

but mind you, `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed size list. You cannot add or remove anything into it. If you want to add or remove something, you should use the 1st version.

P.S: You should use `List` as reference type instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: It's super annoying that they used the same name `ArrayList` twice :)

Comment: varargs do not help to split a string - above claim is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just cast objects around like they're candy. `Arrays.asList()` doesn't return an `ArrayList`, so you can't cast it (it returns an unmodifiable List).

However you can do `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(...));`

Comment: It doesn't return an unmodifiable list, you can still call `set(...)` without any problems.

Comment: @arshajii Fair enough, let's call it "constant sized list".

Answer (score 1):

Does it absolutely need to be an `ArrayList`? Typically you want to use the most generic form.   If you're ok using a `List` just try:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(...);
```

You can still iterate over it the same way you currently are.

Answer (score 1):

```
String CommaSeparated = "item1 , item2 , item3";     
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(CommaSeparated.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
for(String str : items)
{
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use bellow code.

String[] temp;

```
    /* delimiter */
    String delimiter = ",";
    /*
     * given string will be split by the argument delimiter provided.
     */
    temp = parameter.split(delimiter);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int l = 0; l < temp.length; l++)

    {

        list.add(temp[l]);

    }
```